# Class Json - C#

Tags: c#, json, postman

Por favor su ayuda en lo siguiente necesito convertirlo en este json en C# tanto como clase como código, la siguiente estructura json que envió necesito poder generarle el código desde C# y poder enviarlo al endpoint, no he podido ingresar los lstpedido.

Como podría generar bajo esa estructura para poder habilitar la cabecera de lstPedido y pedido.

La estructura lo obtuve en base a paginas que generan la clase en caso tuvieran alguna otra opción me indican.

```
    {
      "LstPedido":{
         "Pedido":[
         {
            "Orden":258141683,
            "Monto_pago":5.0,
            "Categoria":"PORTABILIDAD",
            "Canal_comercial":"",
            "Socio":"No definido",
            "Plan":"No definido",
            "Modalidad":"No definido",
            "Operador":"",
            "Campana_venta":"No definido",
            "Express":"",
            "Motivo_repro":"",
            "Pago_link":"",
            "Observacion":"",
            "Motorizado":"",
            "Cliente":{
 
               "Tipo_documento":"DNI",
               "Numero_documento":"76298229",
               "Apellidos_nombres":"BRYAN CLEVER FLORES MENDIZABAL",
               "Telefono_1":"912936728",
               "Telefono_2":"",
               "Correo_electronico":""
            },
            "Tercero":{
 
               "Tipo_documento":"DNI",
               "Numero_documento":"76298229",
               "Apellidos_nombres":"BRYAN CLEVER FLORES MENDIZABAL",
               "Telefono_1":"912936728",
               "Telefono_2":"",
               "Correo_electronico":""
            },
            "Estado":{
 
               "Estado":"OK",
               "Motivo":"Listo para despacho",
               "Fecha_estado":"2020-11-21",
               "Hora_estado":"21:51:19"
            },
            "Xstore":{
 
               "Cierre":"",
               "Detalle_cierre":""
            },
            "DetallePedido":[
               {
                  "Entrega":{
 
                     "Fecha_pactada":"2020-11-21T15:03:55Z",
                     "Am_pm":"",
                     "Departamento":"LIMA",
                     "Provincia":"LIMA",
                     "Distrito":"VILLA EL SALVADOR",
                     "Direccion":"St 1 Gp 7 Mz B Lt 9 v.e.s",
                     "Referencia":" Av. Modelo con Av. Central"
                  },
                  "DetalleGuia":[
                     {
                        "Guia_remision":"",
                        "SKU":"",
                        "Cantidad":0
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Esas son tu clases del json.
En la clase `Estado` a la propiedad le cambie el nombre y le agregue la Decoracion `[JsonProperty("Estado")]`, porque la propiedad tenia el mismo nombre que la clase y no compila.

No se de donde obtienes tu json, pero si recibes la respuesta desde y tienes el json en un string puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
 //usando la libreria Newtonsoft.Json;
    var resultado = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Pedidos>(CadenaJson);


public class Pedidos
{
    public Lstpedido LstPedido { get; set; }
}

public class Lstpedido
{
    public Pedido[] Pedido { get; set; }
}

public class Pedido
{
    public int Orden { get; set; }
    public float Monto_pago { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string Canal_comercial { get; set; }
    public string Socio { get; set; }
    public string Plan { get; set; }
    public string Modalidad { get; set; }
    public string Operador { get; set; }
    public string Campana_venta { get; set; }
    public string Express { get; set; }
    public string Motivo_repro { get; set; }
    public string Pago_link { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
    public string Motorizado { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public Tercero Tercero { get; set; }
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public Xstore Xstore { get; set; }
    public Detallepedido[] DetallePedido { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public string Tipo_documento { get; set; }
    public string Numero_documento { get; set; }
    public string Apellidos_nombres { get; set; }
    public string Telefono_1 { get; set; }
    public string Telefono_2 { get; set; }
    public string Correo_electronico { get; set; }
}

public class Tercero
{
    public string Tipo_documento { get; set; }
    public string Numero_documento { get; set; }
    public string Apellidos_nombres { get; set; }
    public string Telefono_1 { get; set; }
    public string Telefono_2 { get; set; }
    public string Correo_electronico { get; set; }
}

public class Estado
{
    JsonProperty("Estado")
    public string _Estado { get; set; }
    public string Motivo { get; set; }
    public string Fecha_estado { get; set; }
    public string Hora_estado { get; set; }
}

public class Xstore
{
    public string Cierre { get; set; }
    public string Detalle_cierre { get; set; }
}

public class Detallepedido
{
    public Entrega Entrega { get; set; }
    public Detalleguia[] DetalleGuia { get; set; }
}

public class Entrega
{
    public DateTime Fecha_pactada { get; set; }
    public string Am_pm { get; set; }
    public string Departamento { get; set; }
    public string Provincia { get; set; }
    public string Distrito { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
}

public class Detalleguia
{
    public string Guia_remision { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enriquecer la respuesta ya brindada, Visual Studio (esta es la versión Enterprise en inglés, pero imagino que para Community en español es igual) tiene un truco muy bonito y útil para covertir un JSON en una POCO:

Sólo necesitas ir a Edit - Paste Special - Paste JSON as Classes. Aquí tomé tu JSON y VS me lo convirtió a clases sin problema.

[image: Paste Json as Classes]